# How to validate bank details like account_number, ifsc_code, bank_name and branch_code etc... in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rubygems

In my rails application, I have bank_details table with columns - account_number, ifsc_code, bank_name and branch_code(Only for India). But I don't know how to validates this columns before save it to database.Plese help me in this.

I will appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what did you try so far ?

Answer (score 0):

In your model, you need to add a `validates: your_column`.

For example if you want to make sure that account number is present before you save to the database, you need to add `validates: account_number, presence: true`

There are both pre-built helpers, so you can validate by presence, name, etc, but you can also use a custom method to validate those.

Check out [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) for all the details

Answer (score 0):

There are so many validation that you can apply on your columns, here is a list of possible validation. you can pick as your requirement.

Validation for data should be present

```
validates :account_number, :ifsc_code, :branch_code, :bank_name, presence: true
```

data should be positive numbers only

```
validates :account_number, :branch_code, :numericality => { :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0 }
```

set length of record

```
validates :ifsc_code, length: { is: 11 }
```

validates that the attribute's value is unique right before the object gets saved

```
validates :account_number, uniqueness: true
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model you can have something like this:

```
validates: branch_code
```

which is a standard validation, making sure its present

Or you can do more validation using regex

```
validates :bank_name, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/,
    message: "only allows letters" }
```

Here are some examples of validation:

```
  validates :bank_name, length: { minimum: 2 }
  validates :bank_name, length: { maximum: 500 }
  validates :bank_name, length: { in: 6..20 }
  validates :bank_name, length: { is: 6 }
```

Or use some advance techniques like so:

```
validates :bank_name, presence: true, if: "branch_code.nil?"
```

Answer (score 0):

TransferWise provides an API you can use to validate IFSC codes and Indian account numbers:

IFSC code

```
https://api.transferwise.com/v1/validators/ifsc-code?ifscCode=YESB0236041
```

Account number

```
https://api.transferwise.com/v1/validators/indian-account-number?accountNumber=678911234567891
```

[Documentation here.](https://api-docs.transferwise.com/#recipient-accounts-validate-recipient-fields)